# WhatsApp not passing text from link to Windows Desktop Application

Tags: html, windows, whatsapp

My application needs to be able to send a WhatsApp message with a predefined template using the following link (in my code it obviously contains a real phone number instead of the placeholder):

```
https://wa.me/phone_number?text=Thanks%20for%20reaching%20out!
```

This previously worked up until a few months ago.

Starting from a few months ago I found that it would only paste the message into the WhatsApp Windows application if WhatsApp was previously opened to that contact or if the app was closed, otherwise it would open WhatsApp to that contact but would not paste the predefined message. Does anyone have any solutions for this?

Also I see that the message does indeed get passed to WhatsApp's website, but then their site does not seem to pass the message to the app.

Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like this is indeed the [correct way the link is supposed to be defined](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5913398998672934).

*I am unaware if this issue exists in versions of WhatsApp made for other operating systems.*

**EDIT: This does not seem to be an issue on mobile. This issue might be specifically with the Windows Desktop App which would explain why this issue isn't coming up a lot.**

Comment: Hi. Can you resolve this issue?

Comment: If you click another time in "go to chat" button, the messege appears, finally.

Comment: @Guillermo Acosta
 "If you click another time in "go to chat" button, the message appears, finally" - If I understand your case correctly then that would be because it already opened a chat to that user as it states in my question.